# Narrow useSWRInfinite getKey return type

Tags: typescript, swr

I'm having trouble using `useSWRInfinite` with a `getKey` function that returns an array. The following is a simplified example, and I'm getting this typescript error on the arguments to the fetcher function.

```
Type 'string | [any, ...unknown[]] | readonly [any, ...unknown[]] | Record<any, any>' is not an array type.
```

Is there a way to narrow the return type of the `getKey` function so that I can destructure the array key?

```js
import useSWRInfinite, { SWRInfiniteKeyLoader } from "swr/infinite";

const getKey: SWRInfiniteKeyLoader = (pageNum, page) => {
  const lastItem = page.items[page.items.length - 1];

  return ["Items", lastItem.id];
};

const resp = useSWRInfinite(
  getKey, ([_, lastItemId]) => fetch('/items', {body: JSON.stringify({startingAfter: lastItemId})})
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, params are passed to the fetcher as individual arguments, not as array, so you don't need to destructure them!

As for typing, `SWRInfiniteKeyLoader` uses `any` inside so you won't be able to fully type your function by using this interface. But you can type it manually, like that:

```
// Adjust page type according to your data
const getKey = (pageNum: number, page: { items: Array<{ id: number }> }) => {
  const lastItem = page.items[page.items.length - 1];

  // Use `as const` here
  return ['Items', lastItem.id] as const;
};

// ...
  
  // key is now string and lastItemId is number
  const resp = useSWRInfinite(getKey, (key, lastItemId) =>
    fetch('/items', { body: JSON.stringify({ startingAfter: lastItemId }) })
  );
```

Comment: Thanks! Spreading the arguments fixed most of it. I also found that you can type the fetcher function where the second type argument is the key type.

`const fetcher: Fetcher<Item[], [string, string]> = (key, lastItemId) => {}`

Answer (score 0):

You can add type arguments to SWRInfiniteKeyLoader:

```
const getKey: SWRInfiniteKeyLoader<YourResponseDataType, [string, string | undefined] | null> = (pageNum, page) => {
  const lastItem = page.items[page.items.length - 1];

  return ["Items", lastItem.id];
};
```

I used `string|undefined` for the last item id because it will be undefined for the first page.